# Need explanation for the below python code

Tags: python-3.x

I came across the below line in a piece of code written in python. Couldn't understand it.
Please elaborate.

```
pancake_row = [p == '+' for p in line.split()[0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a list comprehension which is a bit like a condensed for loop which only ever returns a list.

`line` is a str (but we only know this from the code because 'split' is a str method)

`line.split()`generates a list from the str (splitting at whitespace)

`line.split()[0]` is the first element of that list;

`p == '+'` returns a boolean, True or False, and will only ever run once;

So the only possible output is `[True]` or `[False]`